# how can i add styleclass to form tag in xpages

Tags: xpages

I need to add `StyleClass` to a form tag generated in `xPages`.

I don't know if can change this control in new theme but I only need for one `xPage` in my app, this is the code generated:

```
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/blabla.nsf/index.xsp" 
class="xspForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And I need this modify class e.g:

```
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/blabla.nsf/index.xsp" 
class="newclass otherclass" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following to your theme to change the class of the form tag:

```
<control mode="override">
    <name>Form</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>newclass otherclass</value> 
    </property>
</control>
```

**Update:** use the following to only use this on an XPage called index.xsp:

```
<control mode="override">
    <name>Form</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>#{javascript:(view.getPageName() == '/index.xsp')?'newClass otherClass':'xspForm'}</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Comment: But this change all my forms in all xpages of my app?

Comment: yes, it does. You can try calculating the value part by using <value>#{javascript:(view.getPageName() == '/index.xsp')?'newClass otherClass':'xspForm'}</value>

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own xp:form on the XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" createForm="false">
    <xp:form styleClass="newclass otherclass">
         ... add your components here ...
    </xp:form>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: "Add" sorry, my iPhone keyboard changed to "all"

Comment: No, these properties are generated by the XPages engine autoatically. Here you can find a liat of all available properties: http://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xp_form.html

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for responses, unfortunately i only can accept one response.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable form creation in Xpage >All Properties > createForm > False, you can create your own form with your own styleClasses; and that will replace the default form.

[image]