# XPages add form tag to disable Ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile, xpages

I'm using jQuery Mobile (1.2.0) and XPages (8.5.3) and want to disable the Ajax form submission as this appears to be preventing an image being saved (all other text fields are saved successfully).

Can I add `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag using the following?

```
<xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="data-ajax" value="false"></xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
```

I tried using `Form` in Themes (as per [adding styleClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212865/how-can-i-add-styleclass-to-form-tag-in-xpages)) but nothing was added, I could add the `styleClass`.

Comment: You can disable the Ajax form submission individually for each event. Another option is to disable the Ajax refresh globally in the jQuery config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these lines to your theme:

```
<control mode="override">
    <name>Form</name>
    <property>
        <name>attrs</name>
        <complex type="xp_attr">
            <property>
                <name>name</name>
                <value>data-ajax</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>value</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
        </complex>
    </property>
</control>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to this can be setting the `createForm` property in XPages to `false`. This would not generate `form` tag and allow you to create your own using `xp:form`. Then you can add your custom attribute using `xp:this.attrs` just like you did in your query. So you code would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" createForm="true">
    <xp:form id="myForm">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="data-ajax" value="false"></xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
        <!-- All the other controls go here -->
    </xp:form>
</xp:view>
```

This would generate the `form` tag looking something like this:

`<form id="view:myForm" method="post" action="/myPath/myDatabase.nsf/xFormAttrs.xsp" class="xspForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">`